# Add thousand separator with 2 decimals place using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

Currently, what I have is this using jQuery.

**Code.html**

```
<input type="text" class="inputnumber" name="inputnumber" value="" placeholder="">
```

**Code.js**

```
  $('input.inputnumber').keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
      ;
    });
  });
```

Right now, I can only add number with thousand separator in my input field.

```
1,000,000
```

But my goal is to allow user to add thousand separator with 2 decimals like below.

```
1,000,000.00
```

How can I achieve it in my code ? Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current

```
/\D/g, ""
```

will remove *all* non-digit characters, including periods. Use a negated character set instead, removing everything *but* digits and periods, and it'll work as intended:

```
/[^\d.]/
```

To also restrict to 2 decimal places, add this as well:

```
.replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1')
```

which will replace (decimal followed by 2+ digits) with (decimal followed by 2 digits):

```js
$('input.inputnumber').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      // Keep only digits and decimal points:
      .replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
      // Remove duplicated decimal point, if one exists:
      .replace(/^(\d*\.)(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$1$2$3')
      // Keep only two digits past the decimal point:
      .replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1')
      // Add thousands separators:
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputnumber" name="inputnumber" value="1,000,000.00">
```

To allow `-`s at the beginning as well, put `-` inside the character set in initial `.replace`, and also match and remove `-`s not at the beginning of the string with `(?!^)-`:

```js
$('input.inputnumber').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      // Keep only digits, decimal points, and dashes at the start of the string:
      .replace(/[^\d.-]|(?!^)-/g, "")
      // Remove duplicated decimal points, if they exist:
      .replace(/^([^.]*\.)(.*$)/, (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.replace(/\./g, ''))
      // Keep only two digits past the decimal point:
      .replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1')
      // Add thousands separators:
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputnumber" name="inputnumber" value="1,000,000.00">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How to restrict the user to add maximum 2 decimals only ?

Comment: See edit, use another `.replace` to capture the 2 digits after the decimal point, match *more* digits, if they exist, and then replace with just the decimal point followed by those 2 digits

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance , sorry to ask again. but your code still allow the user to add multiple dot (.) . for example 1,000....00 . How to avoid user from entering dot more than one time ? Can you update the code ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Use another replace: `.replace(/^(\d*\.)(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$1$2$3')`

Comment: Hi. sorry to disturb you again. I just want to know how to make this regex also accept the negative numbers ? right now this above regex wont allow if i type -1,000.00 . only allow positive number

Comment: Ok, see edit, add it to the character set and remove `-`s past the beginning